# Magento delete my images after an import of products

Tags: magento-1.9, import, image

I am having a problem with magento. When I do an import of my products with magmi everything goes correctly well.
But I am having a little problem magento removes images on some product. Why he did this?
I show you a video of this problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mrYtAq3qcI8

If you look good, when I select only the color images images appear But when I select a size and a color the first two color image black images appear and when I select the last two color image does not appear.

Do you know why I have this problem?

Comment: are you sure that the images are deleted?please make sure that magento deletes that images.

Comment: @Manik I import my products with magmi I guess it is magmi which then deletes

Answer (score 3):

I can't commet yet because I don't have 50 reputation so I have to create an answer:
This has nothing to do with Magmi but with the Magento image import in 1.9.0.1 (have not tested 1.9.2 yet). I have the same problem and I am not using Magmi.

This bug seems to happen only if you use the same image file/path for multiple products: Magento's configurable swatches have a function to delete duplicate images, the image files are not deleted physically but only the product-image-correlation from the database table. This happens upon saving a product (i.e. each time when a product is sold -> modification of stock). You can read more about this bug and a possible workaround (which has not worked for me) here:
https://github.com/dweeves/magmi-git/issues/183

Answer (score 0):

You can debug this by [enabling query logging](http:///m/e/mezlan-shoes-13778-f-gables-black-ou.jpg).

You'll notice in the trace that this observer is firing: `Mage_ConfigurableSwatches_Model_Observer::productListCollectionLoadAfter()`

If you follow the trace, you'll find where things are being deleted in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Attribute_Backend_Media`

```
protected function _removeDuplicates(&$result)
{

    $fileToId = array();

    foreach (array_keys($result) as $index) {
        if (!isset($fileToId[$result[$index]['file']])) {
            $fileToId[$result[$index]['file']] = $result[$index]['value_id'];
        } elseif ($fileToId[$result[$index]['file']] != $result[$index]['value_id']) {
            $this->deleteGallery($result[$index]['value_id']);
            unset($result[$index]);
        }
    }

    $result = array_values($result);
    return $this;
}

public function deleteGallery($valueId)
{
    if (is_array($valueId) && count($valueId)>0) {
        $condition = $this->_getWriteAdapter()->quoteInto('value_id IN(?) ', $valueId);
    } elseif (!is_array($valueId)) {
        $condition = $this->_getWriteAdapter()->quoteInto('value_id = ? ', $valueId);
    } else {
        return $this;
    }

    $this->_getWriteAdapter()->delete($this->getMainTable(), $condition);
    return $this;
}
```

It seems that when you enable configurable swatches (it may happen all the time, but I'm only noticing it when using built in configurable swatches), Magento will try to self-clean any duplicate images it finds with your products.  Pretty stupid feature if you ask me.

One solution would be to rewrite the function to something like

```
protected function _removeDuplicates(&$result)
{
    $fileToId = array();

    foreach (array_keys($result) as $index) {
        if (!isset($fileToId[$result[$index]['file']])) {
            $fileToId[$result[$index]['file']] = $result[$index]['value_id'];
        } elseif ($fileToId[$result[$index]['file']] != $result[$index]['value_id']) {
            # Don't actually delete from the DB, just don't show on frontend
            # $this->deleteGallery($result[$index]['value_id']);
            unset($result[$index]);
        }
    }

    $result = array_values($result);
    return $this;
}
```